# Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 1 - It inserted no value in the first row

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This is my table .. I only have 2 rows of data in my database .. but when I refresh the page i got that error and the datatable have 3 rows of data .. the first row doesnt have any value so the retrieved data is 3 rows instead of 2

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="tbl">
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Delegation Name</th>
              <th>Address(s)</th>
              <th>Contact Number</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <th>Delegation Name</th>
              <th>Address(s)</th>
              <th>Contact Number</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            </tfoot>
```

This is my javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
$(document).ready(function () {
    retrieve_user();
});
function retrieve_user(){
  $.ajax({
    url:'conn/callFunc.php',
    method:'POST',
    data:{
      _trans:'retrieve_user'
    },
    success:function(msg){
            var table = $('#tbl').DataTable();
            table.rows.add( $(msg) ).draw();
    }
  })
}
    </script>
```

---

This is in my conn/callfunc.php

```
else if($trans === 'retrieve_user'){
    echo $md->retrieve_user();
}
```

---

This is my query.php

```
public function retrieve_user(){

    $res = null;

    $ret = $this->Connect()->prepare("select id, name, age ,address from tbl_user");
    $ret->execute();
    $ret->bind_result($id,$name,$age,$address);
    while ($ret->fetch()) {

        $res.= "
            <tr>
                <td>$id</td>
                <td>$name</td>
                <td>$age</td>
                <td>$address</td>
            </tr>
        ";
    }
    return $res;    
}
```

Comment: You fire `retrieve_user();` everytime you load the page because of document.ready()

Comment: Yes, and I don't quite understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: first row does not contains any value, that's why that issue is coming

Comment: use array_filter() to resolve this issue and update your array before while loop so that it can remove empty elements every time.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is coming due to empty array elements. You need to use `array_filter()` to remove empty array elements like below:

```
public function retrieve_user(){
    $res = null;
    $ret = $this->Connect()->prepare("select id, name, age ,address from tbl_user");
    $ret->execute();
    $ret->bind_result($id,$name,$age,$address);
    $ret->fetch = array_filter($ret->fetch);
    while ($ret->fetch()) {
    if(!empty($id){
    $res.= "
        <tr>
            <td>$id</td>
            <td>$name</td>
            <td>$age</td>
            <td>$address</td>
        </tr>
    ";
    }
 }
return $res;    
}
```

Comment: I still get an error and retrieved rows that doesnt have a data on it.

Comment: you can also use if condition so that empty row will never come

Comment: check my updated answer. add if condition after while loop

Comment: Please check once otherwise we can do with some other solution.

Comment: It is still the same. retrieveed like 8 rows with no data

Comment: Issue is coming while adding data in database or in view?

Comment: error is coming while adding data in database? Please clear

Comment: How you are adding? Please give some clarity to resolve the issue?

Comment: the thing is i've change templates and i insert data manually to database. I want to check first and solve the datatable issue

Comment: the solution i give you come into play when you try to insert data into database with while loop

Comment: then no empty row will be added in the database

Comment: ohh i see. is there a solution you know just to retrieve without empty values

Comment: Yes you can do it with jquery or js

Comment: you can hide first div on page refresh but that is just a trick not logical

Comment: window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('row')[0].style.display = 'none';
}

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('row')[0] - Gets the first element in the DOM with class name as row.

Comment: then add style.display = 'none' - Javascript equivalent of the CSS display: none.